# What does void(U::*)(void) mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I was looking at the implementation of the `is_class` template in Boost, and ran into some syntax I can't easily decipher.

```
    template <class U> static ::boost::type_traits::yes_type is_class_tester(void(U::*)(void));
    template <class U> static ::boost::type_traits::no_type is_class_tester(...);
```

How do I interpret `void(U::*)(void)` above?  I'm familiar with C, so it appears somewhat analogous to `void(*)(void)`, but I don't understand how `U::` modifies the pointer.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: The `U::*` denotes that the function the pointer points to is a member of `U`, necessary because in C++, *under the covers*, the first argument of a member function is a pointer to what object to call it on.

Comment: @Austin Hyde: for those functions/methods that are attached to a class, at least, for free methods or class static methods it's not the case.

Comment: @Matthieu, very true. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`*` indicates a pointer, because you can access its contents by writing `*p`. `U::*` indicates a pointer to a member of class `U`. You can access its contents by writing `u.*p` or `pu->*p` (where `u` is an instance of `U`).

So, in your example, `void (U::*)(void)` is a pointer **to a member of `U`** that is a function taking no arguments and returning no value.

Example:

```
class C { void foo() {} };

typedef void (C::*c_func_ptr)(void);

c_func_ptr myPointer = &C::foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

Start from U, then work inside out.

The declared type is a pointer to a member function from class U taking void arguments and returning void.

Comment: But...  `U` is a class, not a pointer.  You mean, the parameter to `is_class_tester` is a pointer to a member function?  That would make sense.

Comment: Note that here the type (of the method pointer) is not named (as it is in an error message). Thus in this case U is the name of the class from which the method is called.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, it is analogous to a function pointer. Rather, this is a pointer to member function, where the member is of the class `U`.

The difference in type is necessitated because member functions have an implicit `this` pointer, as they cannot be called without an instance. Getting rid of the template might make it a bit easier:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar(void);
};
```

`void(*)(void)` won't do, as this has no way to communicate an instance of the class. Rather, we need:

```
void (foo::*)(void)
```

Indicating that this function pointer requires an instance of `foo`.

---

For what it's worth, you use them like this:

```
typedef void (foo::*func_ptr)(void);

foo f;
foo* fp = &f;
func_ptr func = &foo::bar;

(f.*func)();
(fp->*func)();
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer to a member function of class U.
it's quite similar to

void(*)(void)

but it points to a member function of class U.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask this very same question, but it has already been asked. Unfortunately, none of the existing answers really answered the question. Not for me at least. I had to puzzle it out. I wanted to ask the same question as the OP, plus some. My question: WTF is this `is_class_tester (void (U::*)(void))` stuff, and how does this construct work in the context of SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error)?

With some simplification, Boost uses the construct as follows:

```
template <typename U>
char is_class_tester (void (U::*)(void));

template <typename U>
TypeBiggerThanChar is_class_tester (...);

template <typename T>
struct IsClass {
   static const bool value = sizeof (is_class_tester<T>(0)) == 1;
};
```

Some observations:

1. Those function templates are not really function templates. They are just forward declarations of a pair of overloaded function templates. The function templates themselves are never defined. Seeing that this is so and understanding how this works without needing the templates to ever be defined is one of the key elements in understanding this construct.
2. The answers that talked about how to use this first function template missed the boat. You can't use this function template because its definition doesn't exist.
3. Note that thanks to that arcane argument, the first of the two function templates make sense only when the type `T` is a class. Fundamental types and pointers don't have member functions. The first declaration is invalid syntax for non-class types.
4. Contrast that to the second of the overloaded function templates, which is valid syntax for all template parameters, and the function (if it existed) would take any arguments thrown at it thanks to its variadic ... argument. (Aside: This is vaguely reminiscent of my favorite one-line C program that can solve any problem in the world, given properly formatted user input.)
5. While the function template declarations aren't usable as functions, the declarations can be used in simple compile-time queries such as a query about the return type. The actual definition isn't needed for this kind of query. Only the prototype is needed.
6. This is exactly what the class template `IsClass` does to define the compile-time constant `IsClass<SomeType>::value`.

So how does `IsClass<SomeType>::value` gets its value, and how does it do that at compile time? The compiler has to either make sense of `sizeof (is_class_tester<T>(0))` or give up trying. We need to look at two cases based on whether the type `SomeType` is or is not a class.

Case 1: `SomeType` is a class.
Here both template declarations are valid syntax, so the compiler has two viable candidates to choose from. The compiler can and must the first function template because the selection rules dictate that a variadic function gets lowest priority in the selection. This selected function returns a char. Since sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1, `IsClass<SomeType>::value` will be true in the case that `SomeType` is a class.

Case 2: `SomeType` is not a class.
Here is where SFINAE kicks in. The first function template declaration is invalid syntax. The compiler can't just give up here because of SFINAE. It has to keep looking for an alternative, and the second function template declaration fits the bill. The only viable function returns a `TypeBiggerThanChar`, definition elided, but hopefully obvious. All we want is sizeof() this thing. It's bigger than a char, so `IsClass<SomeType>::value` will be false in the case that `SomeType` is not a class.

Comment: They answered the question, the OP didn't ask about the rest. You could just ask a new question about how it works and provide one of the answers yourself if you want that to be easily accessible on SO

Comment: @Georg: They answered the question, but not in the context of its use. (Nobody caught that fact that the function templates were declared but not defined, for example.) Regarding the larger context of your comment: I'm still a newbie here (just a month), but my take is that replicated questions are highly frowned upon at SO. So I added this as a necromanced answer rather than starting a brand new question. If that is the wrong take, let me know.

Comment: The context didn't matter for the question asked, he only wanted to know about the member function pointer syntax. While you shouldn't open duplicate questions, this one wouldn't be because it's about how `is_class_tester()` works instead of what that syntax is :)