# callback function syntax

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does void(U::*)(void) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280828/what-does-voiduvoid-mean)

Considering the following:

```
template <class T>
class myButtoncb  {
   private:
      T *ptr;
      void (T::*cback) (void)
}
```

What I understand is:

```
void (*cback) (void)
```

Which is nothing but a function pointer that to a function that returns void, and takes no argument.

What I dont understand is, what is the importance of `T::`? Isn't it enough to declare
only like `void (*cback) (void)` ?

Comment: -1 for posting a dupe (even if this wasn't a dupe, it should be pretty obvious from basic C++ syntax what this means.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This says that it's a member function that has a `this` pointer. Otherwise, it would be a free function, wouldn't have any idea what object it was operating on, and wouldn't be able to access any non-static member functions or member variables.

Comment: That's a nice way of looking it. :).

Answer (score 1):

From [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html)

> Is the type of "pointer-to-member-function" different from "pointer-to-function"?
>
> Yep.

[Link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html) which I've provided to you has a lot of information about this topic.

Comment: @besworland The link isn't bad but there isn't really _that much_ information there. Plus, providing information directly would arguably be [better than providing a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @jogojapan my answer provide not only the link for further reading, but also gives the precise answer to "Isn't it enough to declare only like void (*cback) (void) ?"

Comment: @Sergey Come on... what your answer is saying is basically _Yes, there is a difference between `*` and `T::*` but if you want to know what that difference is, go to this FAQ_. (And even the FAQ has just a few lines, not really _a lot of information on this topic._) Now I didn't say there is anything wrong with that -- I didn't downvote it  -- but it isn't really what I'd call a _good answer_.

Comment: @jogojapan Should I add to the answer information from the book to make you satisfied? For example "Pointer that encapsulates the class type as well as the member type to which the pointer points" from the C++ Primer by Stanley Lippman and Barbara Moo.

Comment: @Sergey No need to satisfy me if you don't want... (I merely commented on besworland's remark). But, as an example, there is a good answer already on the dup question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3280859/777186.

Comment: @jogojapan thank you for constructive comments and downvote

Answer (score 0):

The function, you pass there, must be declared inside the class T - the template parameter of myButtoncb. So you can use a function like the following:

```
class A
{
public:
     void foo(void);
};


myButton<A> b;
b.cback = &A::foo;
```